# Error installing gnureadline via pip

Tags: python, linux, pip

I broke my IPython setup whilst trying to upgrade to IPython 2.0.  The installation fails when `gnureadline` is being installed.  I originally had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa) but I fixed it.  Now I'm getting this error:

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/gnureadline.so

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libreadline.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libhistory.a'

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/jj/0w0dd3n16jq4g5579g6c7h040000gn/T/pip_build_root/gnureadline/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/jj/0w0dd3n16jq4g5579g6c7h040000gn/T/pip-iJITYv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jj/0w0dd3n16jq4g5579g6c7h040000gn/T/pip_build_root/gnureadline
Storing complete log in /Users/mc/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`

Reference: 
[Ipython no readline available and pip install readline error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622490/ipython-no-readline-available-and-pip-install-readline-error)

Comment: install in terminal `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`, it is working fine and then `pip install gnureadline==6.3.3`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the above. The `libffi` package sorted it out for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

On OSX 10.14.5 -

```
brew install ncurses
```

then

```
pip install gnureadline
```

Answer (score 0):

install in terminal sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev, it is working fine and then pip install gnureadline==6.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora users:

```
dnf install ncurses-devel
```