# Installing readline module in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I had older version of python pre-installed on Ubuntu. I recently installed new python3.4 version without removing the older one. In python3 I am not able to see the command history. Searching around, I found that readline module is responsible for the command history and it is missing in python3. So I installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
```

It gets installed without any error but python3 still has no readline module. How do I install it to get command history in python3.

Comment: That's for building from source. You could also get 3.4 from the [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes).

Answer (score 11):

I was experiencing the same problem and found my fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622490/ipython-no-readline-available-and-pip-install-readline-error).

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
sudo -H pip3 install readline
```

I'm not sure how universal the answer is though, you might need more packages (for example the `libreadline6-dev` package you mentioned) before you could install `readline` with `pip3`

Comment: This seems to work with the system-installed Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, as of June 2017.